# Auto newline in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In my text documents, I often want to keep lines to 80 characters. So I watch the column number in the lower right corner and go to a new line once I get close to 80.

The problem is, when I have a long paragraph, and then I decide to edit the first sentence, I have to realign the whole thing manually.

Is there a way to get Notepad++ to automatically add newline characters in the right place as I type? I'm decidedly not talking about word wrap; I want actual `\n` characters put in the document. I'm fine with plugin suggestions or macro code or whatever can work.

Comment: Your requested function is a bit strange, usually web only want to view the text only so Word Warp is here, however if you still want to splitting every n character, you may try to find `(?<=.{80})\s` and replace with `$0\n`

Comment: First of all, this may seem strange; however it's not irregular for programmers to keep comments and text files wrapped to 80 characters per line. And that regex doesn't seem to work for me, I don't know why. I do have this regex already: `\n(.{0,80})(?: |$)(.*)(?<=.{81})` -> `\n$1\n$2`, but I'd like to be able to have Notepad++ do it in real-time.